# Microsoft Access - I want my mainform to create X records in subform base on fields automatically

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, subform, insertafter

I been putting a lot of thought into the logic behind this, and I can't seem to figure out the best way to handle this problem.

1 - Afterinsert

2 - unbound fields + button to insert X times

3 - I am open for suggestions

The form

[image]

The relationship

[image]

I was debating on using `AfterInsert` to handle everything. Since `NoOfBoxes` will decide the amount of records and I would only need to duplicate the value of `MergeNo` and `isCommission` to the subform. But the problem is, I need to also auto fill the item, which made me think of solutions number 2.

The reasoning behind going with number 2 is; my receive report header doesn't contains the item information and since a subform can only have 1 type of item but multiple of them. I was hitting toward number 2.

Solution number 2 would be multiple unbound fields which pulled the information into a combo box, or enter the information needed and hit a button which will then transfer all that data to the subform and create the correct amount of records.

unbound fields = itemcode, mergeNo, isCommission, and NoOfBoxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a Numbers table with integers from 1 or 0 to an appropriate number, you can then say something like:

```
INSERT INTO ATable ( MergeNo, IsCommission )
SELECT [Forms]![aForm]![MergeNo] AS MergeNo, 
       [Forms]![aForm]![IsCommission ] AS IsCommission 
FROM Numbers
WHERE Numbers.Number<=[Forms]![aForm]![NoOfBoxes]
```

Do not forget that if the numbers table starts from 0, it is less than, not less than or equal to.

Comment: Are you implying on creating a loop with the insert? and continue until I hit `NoOfBoxes`

Comment: No, I am not the Numbers table has integers from 0 or 1 to at least the maximum NoOfBoxes, the SQL then SELECTS from the numbers table to get the required rows.

Comment: I don't understand how the insert query will insert X amount into the table base on a where clause.

And isn't it bad to have a table just to hold numbers, it seems semi unproductive.

Comment: Numbers tables take little space and are very useful http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable You will find that the query runs very quickly indeed, rather that an RBAR approach. Why not try the query on a copy of your front-end? You can just use SELECT, rather than INSERT, to see it work.

Comment: I dont think your method will work, since I just read that microsoft access does not allow multiple values to be inserted in 1 insert statement.

Comment: I tested before I posted and I have been using this stuff for many years. You are not running multiple insert statements, you are running one insert statement, just the same as if you said `INSERT INTO aTable (Field1, Field2) SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM bTable`

Comment: That is only inserting 1 record, I need to do multiple. That was the problem I was facing.

Comment: How many numbers are in your numbers table? What is the value of NoOfBoxes?

Comment: my NoOfBoxes can go from 1 to 99

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60557/discussion-between-fionnuala-and-joshua-dalley).